# Как удалить пару ключ-значение, в зависимости от типа значения с помощью for in?

Tags: javascript

```
    var menu = {
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      title: "My menu"
    };


    function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof (obj[key] == 'number')) {
          delete obj[key];
        }
    }
  }

    multiplyNumeric(menu);
    console.log(menu)
```

нужно удалить свойство если его значение число, или строка, в зависимости от условия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас лишние скобки в условии:

```
if (typeof (obj[key] == 'number')) {
```

Выражение `typeof (obj[key] == 'number')` сводится к `typeof(true)` или `typeof(false)` и возвращает строку `"boolean"`, в результате `if` всегда выполняется и удаляются все значения из `obj`

Рабочий пример:

```js
var menu = {
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    title: "My menu"
};
    
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
}

multiplyNumeric(menu);
console.log(menu)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var menu = {
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      title: "My menu"
    };


    function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
        const v = {};

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] !== 'number') {
                v[key] = obj[key];
                // Не изменит старый обект если надо изменить просто замени v[key] = obj[key] на delete obj[key];
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    console.log(multiplyNumeric(menu));
    console.log(menu);
```